# Java 8 Stream API toMap converting to TreeMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
public class Message {
    private int id;
    private User sender;
    private User receiver;
    private String text;   
    private Date senddate;
..
}
```

I have

```
List<Message> list= new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to transform them to

```
TreeMap<User,List<Message>> map
```

I know how to do transform to HashMap using

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Message::getSender));
```

But I need TreeMap with:
 Key  - User with newest message senddate first
Value - List sorted by senddate newest first

Part of User class

```
    public class User{
    ...
    private List<Message> sendMessages;
    ...

   public List<Message> getSendMessages() {
        return sendMessages;
    }

}
```

User comparator:

```
     public class Usercomparator implements Comparator<User> {
        @Override
        public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
            return o2.getSendMessages().stream()
.map(message -> message.getSenddate())
.max(Date::compareTo).get()
           .compareTo(o1.getSendMessages().stream()
.map(message1 -> message1.getSenddate())
.max(Date::compareTo).get());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are planning to have key of type `User`. Does this class implement `Comparable<User>`? If not how do you want to compare them?

Comment: Could you post your `User` class? Also, a sample input / output?

Comment: I added part of User class and compatator

Comment: Also, a sample input / output because it's not clear what you want to do here. Please expand.

Comment: As a side note: `Comparator<Message> byDate=Comparator.comparing(Message::getSenddate); Comparator<User> userComparator=Comparator.comparing(user -> Collections.max(user.getSendMessages(), byDate), byDate);`…

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use overloaded [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) method and pass `TreeMap` as [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```
TreeMap<User, List<Message>> map = list
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Message::getSender,
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(new Usercomparator()), toList()));
```

Comment: The values won't be sorted.

Answer (score 12):

If your list is sorted then just use this code for sorted map.

```
Map<String, List<WdHour>> pMonthlyDataMap = list
                .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WdHour::getName, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: This solution will give you the Map sorted by name, not by the sort order of the list.