# Java 8: How to stream a list into a list of lists?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of objects that need to be sorted and grouped:

```
static class Widget {
    // ...
    public String getCode() { return widgetCode; }
    public String getName() { return widgetName; }
}

List<Widget> widgetList = Arrays.asList(
    // several widgets with codes and names
);
```

I want to group the list into a list-of-lists, grouped by *widgetCode*, with the elements of each sub-list in the order they were encountered in the original list.  I know that I can group them into a Map of lists using the `groupingBy` Collector:

```
Map<String,List<Widget>> widgetMap = widgetList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Widget::getCode));
```

I do not take for granted that the keys are sorted, so I've taken the extra step of loading the whole thing into a SortedMap type:

```
SortedMap<String,List<Widget>> sortedWidgetMap = new TreeMap<String,List<Widget>>(
    widgetList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Widget::getCode))
);
```

I know I can get a Collection from *sortedWidgetMap* by using .values(), and I guess it is an ordered collection because it comes from an ordered map type, so that's my current solution:

```
Collection<List<Widget>> widgetListList = new TreeMap<String,List<Widget>>(
    widgetList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Widget::getCode))
).values();
widgetListList.forEach(System.out::println);  // do something with the data
```

This works so far, but I'm not confident that the resulting widgetListList is actually guaranteed to be in the right order (i.e. by *widgetCode*) or that the sub-lists will be built in the order they were found in the original list.  Also, I think it must be possible to use the Stream API alone to achieve the output I want.  So, how can I do this better?

Comment: For the sorting, you can give the `TreeMap` a `Comparator` to sort by.

Comment: From `SortedMap.values()`'s javadoc : "The collection's iterator returns the values in ascending order of the corresponding keys.", so no worry about the order with your solution (efficiency can probably be improved though)

Comment: Well, you could provide a sorted map to `groupingBy`, e.g. like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116264/java-8-stream-api-tomap-converting-to-treemap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, referring to a [question that is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35116264/3182664) (in fact, I nearly considered it to be a duplicate...), the `groupBy` call comes in different flavors, and one of them allows passing in a factory for the map that is to be created.

So there is no need to explicitly wrap the result of the "simple" `groupBy` call into the creation of a new `TreeMap`, because you can create the `TreeMap` directly. This map (and its `values()` collection!) will be ordered by the key. The values of the map are lists, which are created using the downstream collector `toList()`, which explicitly says that it will collect the results *in encounter order*.

So the following should indeed be a simple, correct and efficient solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CollectToListOfList {
    static class Widget {
        String code;
        String name;

        Widget(String code, String name) {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return code + ": " + name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Widget> widgetList = Arrays.asList(
            new Widget("0", "A"), 
            new Widget("1", "B"), 
            new Widget("2", "C"),
            new Widget("3", "D"), 
            new Widget("0", "E"), 
            new Widget("1", "F"), 
            new Widget("2", "G"),
            new Widget("3", "H"), 
            new Widget("0", "I"), 
            new Widget("1", "J"));

        Collection<List<Widget>> result = widgetList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Widget::getCode, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
            .values();

        for (List<Widget> list : result) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to correct previous post based on clarification.  Only difference between answer(s) by others is that the values() result is fed into an ArrayList constructor to create a List of Lists.

```java
      // Create some data
      Random r = new Random(29);
      String codes = "ABCD";
      List<Widget> widgetList = r.ints(10, 0, 4).mapToObj(
            n -> new Widget(codes.substring(n, n + 1), "N" + i++)).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());

      // Now create the list of lists.

      List<List<Widget>> listofWidgets = new ArrayList<>(
            widgetList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Widget::getCode,
                  TreeMap::new,
                  Collectors.toList())).values());

      // Display them
      for (List<?> list : listofWidgets) {
         System.out.println(list);
      }
```

Widget class

```java
    class Widget {
       String widgetCode;
       String widgetName;

       public Widget(String wc, String wn) {
          widgetCode = wc;
          widgetName = wn;
       }

       public String getCode() {
          return widgetCode;
       }

       public String getName() {
          return widgetName;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "{" + widgetCode + ":" + widgetName + "}";
       }
    }
```

Comment: No, that's not my goal.  What I want is a list of List<Widget>s.  The first element in the List would be a List of all <Widget>s with the widgetCode "A", the second would be a List of all <Widget>s with the widgetCode "B", and so on.  Maybe my toy problem is too silly to make it clear!

Comment: You problem is fine.  And apparently I was the only one who didn't understand. Thanks for the clarification.